# Vimeo API Trigger Event

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

We are using Vimeo to host corporate training videos and was wondering if there is a way using the API to trigger an event once the playback is complete?!.. We're trying to log when users have fully watched the training material.

Any suggestions welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Vimeo player fires many different javascript events. Finish is one of these events. You can find out more here : https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#events

Answer (score 0):

I set this up as a page on my server, and it works. Once the video player passes 3 seconds, the words You just made my function run. appear inside the  tags.

I've included the full page code -- most of the javascript is from the Vimeo API example, and you wouldn't need it.

A few things I ran into - I couldn't get this to run on Jquery 1.10.X -- it looks like this may only work with jquery 1.7.2.

Also note, once the element is shown, it stays shown - so if you wanted it to hide itself again if the person rewinds the player... you'd have to build that in, probably with an "else" statement.

Last, I only tested this in Chrome, so check with your local Internet Exploder before going production.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />

<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<iframe id="player1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855315?api=1&player_id=player1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

<p>Video status: <span class="status">...</span></p>
<p><button>Play</button> <button>Pause</button></p>
<h3 id="show"></h3><!-- thats where the message will show -->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // WordPress needs jquery like this...
var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
    player = $f(iframe),
    status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    status.text('ready');

    player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

function onPause(id) {
    status.text('paused');

}

function onFinish(id) {
    status.text('finished');
}

function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
    status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
    var time = data.seconds; //I added this var and the little if below...that's it.
    if (time > 3) {
    show.innerHTML = "You just made my function run."; }
}
// add an appropriate event listener


});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using Vimoe player.js

```
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

and below is the code which i have also integrate onto a website to know how many logged in users watched the complete video.

```
player.on('ended', function(){ 
   // Video Finished 
    // ajax call for custom event in WordPress
    $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php" ) ?>',
            data : {
                action: "create_update_user",
                user_id : "<?php echo $user->ID; ?>",
                post_id : "<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>",
                status : 'complete' },
            dataType : "post",
            type: "post",
            success: function(response){
            }
     });
```

Hope it is useful because player.js is more useful instead of froogaloop2.min.js

thanks